# How to read first character of string inside an array without using string.charAt()?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array with strings:

```
["1234", "1223", "5454", "abc", "abdd"]
```

And I want to read the first character of each string and put it into an new array:

```
["1", "1", "5", "a", "a"]
```

I tried using `string[0]` but seems it won't work inside a for loop in Javascript, any ideas to work around it?

for @Ryan 's request here's my code below:

```
filteredsubstr = substr.filter(function(item){ //substr is an array with strings.
    for (var key in item){
        if(key != 0 || key !=''){
            var fckey = key[0];
            return fckey;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `string[x]` doesn’t stop working in a for loop; please show your attempt.

Comment: `substr`, `substring`, `[0]` - so, `arr.map(x =>x [0])` should do the trick

Comment: @Ryan code updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `map` instead of `filter`.

```js
var strings = ["1234", "1223", "5454", "abc", "abdd"]

var firstChars = strings.map(function (string) {
    return string[0];
})

console.log(firstChars)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), because strings are iterables.

```js
var array = ["1234", "1223", "5454", "abc", "abdd"];
    result = array.map(([a]) => a);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
var testArr = ["1234", "1223", "5454", "abc", "abdd"],
newArr = [];

testArr.forEach( function(str){
    newArr.push(str.substring(0,1));
});
```

Better functional and efficient version.

```
var testArr = ["1234", "1223", "5454", "abc", "abdd"];


function getFirst(arr){
   return arr.map(function(str){
       return str.substring(0,1);
   });
}

console.log(getFirst(testArr));
```

**Best videos for understanding the array methods**
[The Array ForEach Method](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-the-array-map-method)

Comment: That `forEach` + `push` is a `map`.