# Getting the first characters of each string in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(function(animal) {
     for(animal = 0; animal <= animals.length-1; animal++) {
            return animals[animal].charAt(animal);
     }
});

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Hi, thru this piece of code i want to output the string `HelloWorld`, which is formed by the first characters of each string/element in the animals array. However, the output is instead `HHHHHHHHHH`. I don't know if the for loop is the problem here?

Could someone please tell me why the code produces such an output and how i can modify it in order for the desired result to be returned successfully?

I'm just a novice for now & that's why your help will play a tremendous part in my growth as a programmer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read first character of string inside an array without using string.charAt()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740229/how-to-read-first-character-of-string-inside-an-array-without-using-string-chara)

Comment: animals.map(function(s) { return s[0]; }).join("");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) in and of itself.

Try:

```js
// Animals.
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog']
    
// Secret Message.
const secretMessage = animals.map((animal) => animal[0]).join('')
    
// Log.
console.log(secretMessage) // "HelloWorld"
```

Or alternatively:

```js
// Animals.
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog']

// Secret Message.
const secretMessage = animals.reduce((accumulator, animal) => accumulator + animal[0], '')

// Log.
console.log(secretMessage) // "HelloWorld"
```

Comment: Plus 1 for using `.reduce()` in this context -- expanded my use case scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

The map method does the for loop for you. So all you need in the function is animal[0]

```
let secretMessage = animals.map(function(animal) {
     return animal[0]
});
```

This will return every first character in every string in the array, animals. Everything else you have is right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need inner loop:

```js
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(function(animal) {
  return animal.charAt(0); // or simply animal[0]
});

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that you have a loop inside the map function, which already loops the array.

The correct code is

```
animals.map(x=>x[0]).join('');
//or
animals.map(function(animal){
    return animal[0]; //First letter of word
}).join(''); //Array -> String
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the code:

```
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(function(animal) {
    return animal.charAt(0);
});

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```js
let animals = [
  'Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 
  'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 
  'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'
];
console.log(animals.map(e => e[0]).join(""));
```

Comment: For ES5 or less use this:

    animals.map(function(s) { return s[0]; }).join("");

For ES6:
() => { }

Answer (score 0):

```
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(function(animals) {
return animals[0];
});

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

or

```
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(animals => animals[0]);

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` `array` function take callback function as an argument and return new array so that can use this method to get our result see the syntax below:

```
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];


 const secretMessage = animals.map(animals => {

   return animals[0];
 })

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

now when .map method is applied on the animals array its return only the first element of the each string because we use `animals[0]` which read only first element of each string so our output is `HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const secretMessage = animals.map(animal => {
  return animal[0];
})

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution : ---**

```
const user = 'Anisul Haque Bhuiyan';

const username = user.toLowerCase().split(' ').map((elem) => elem[0]).join('');
console.log(username);
```

> Output : 'ahb'